# mysql create database and user script

Tags: mysql, database, bash, scripting, centos

Question Rewritten:

```
HOMEDIR="ftpuser"
REMOTEIP="1.1.1.1"
MYSQLPASS="password"

Q1="DROP USER "$HOMEDIR"_shop;"
Q2="DROP DATABASE "$HOMEDIR"_shop;"
Q3="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "$HOMEDIR"_shop;"
Q4="GRANT ALL ON "$HOMEDIR"_shop TO '"$HOMEDIR"_shop'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQLPASS';"
Q5="GRANT ALL ON "$HOMEDIR"_shop TO '"$HOMEDIR"_shop'@'anotherip' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQLPASS';"
# Need to grant permissions from another server as well
Q6="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}${Q4}${Q5}${Q6}"

echo $SQL
echo " "
ssh -p 8899 root@$REMOTEIP "mysql -u root -p "$SQL""
```

I then run:

```
/root/testing/migratesite.sh
```

And get:

```
bash: DROP: command not found
bash: CREATE: command not found
bash: GRANT: command not found
bash: GRANT: command not found
bash: FLUSH: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me, mysql 5.0.51, BASH 3.2.39. Are you running it inside another script? Does that run if you run it via the command line?

Comment: I have redone my question to explain exactly what I am doing rather than what I am basing it on! Hope that helps!

Comment: I'd say that this `ssh -p 8899 root@$REMOTEIP "mysql -u root -p $SQL""` can't work because of the quotes...but I don't have a machine to try it out yet...try to escape the quotes around $SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing quotes and a proper mysql client command line:

```
ssh -p 8899 root@$REMOTEIP "mysql -u root -p -e \"$SQL\""
```

You need to escape the quotes around the $SQL variable so they get passed to the remote shell, else they get interpreted by the local shell (that's why you get DROP: command not found, the semi colon is interpreted by the shell.) Also, to have the mysql client to execute a command you have to pass the -e command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
ssh -p 8899 root@$REMOTEIP "echo \"$SQL\" | mysql -u root --password=$SQL_PASS"
```

Comment: This will fail as well due to lack of quoting. This has the added problem that mysql client will interpret the SQL as the password.

Comment: Yeah, should have changed `-p` to `--password=$PASS_VARIABLE`. Corrected.

Comment: As long as $PASS_VARIABLE gets read from the arguments (and not stored within the script) that should be fine.